# System shutdown after entering my username and password

Tags: 18.04, startup

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.

Now, whenever I enter my username and password, it freezes for a few seconds showing a blank purple screen.  After that it shows the Ubuntu logo with the 5 dots, and then simply shuts down.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I managed a workaround by -

selecting the "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-32-generic" instead of the default "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-45-generic" in the Advanced Boot options.

I'm running 18.04 and am dual booting windows.
I am very new to Ubuntu. I have no idea why this is happening, I have a hunch that it is an issue with the graphics drivers.

Update -
I updated my graphics drivers and all is well now. It boots up normally.